# Deeplinking Componentless Routes With Child Routes in Angular

Tags: angular, routes

Is there any chance to deeplink within componentless routes if they having children? Starting from here:

**The Router-Module:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ 
    CatalogComponent, ProductComponent, PictureComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogComponent, 
        children :[
            { path: '', component: ProductComponent, outlet: "product"}, 
            { path: '', component: PictureComponent, outlet: "picture"}
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**The Catalog Components Template**

```
<div>Catalog
   <router-outlet name="product"></router-outlet>
   <router-outlet name="picture"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

What was achieved here is that 2 components are loaded in parallel when navigating to /catalog. This works!

But know I want to advance this componentless routes with childroutes like so:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ 
    CatalogComponent, ProductComponent, PictureComponent, ItemComponent, StackComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogComponent, 
        children :[
            { path: '', component: ProductComponent, outlet:"product", 
              children :[
                     { path: 'x', component: ItemComponent}
              ]
            },
            { path: '', component: PictureComponent, outlet: "picture",
              children :[
                     { path: 'y', component: StackComponent}
              ]
            }
        ]}
    ])
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule,
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I was hoping to achieve this component structure:

```
CatalogComponent -> ProductComponent
                                    -> ItemComponent
                 -> PictureComponent
                                    -> StackComponent
```

Whereas ProductComponent and PictureComponent are rendered in parallel and ItemComponent/StackComponent behaves XOR depending on the URL:

```
URL: catalog/x

CatalogComponent -> ProductComponent
                                    -> ItemComponent
                 -> PictureComponent

URL: catalog/y

CatalogComponent -> ProductComponent

                 -> PictureComponent
                                    -> StackComponent
```

So using multiple pathless routes is a way to load multiple components in parallel on the same page, kind of auxiliary routes. But when it comes to deeplinking it does not seem to work at all. Is this possible in Angular at all?

Comment: I have played here but i still didnt find solution.
https://github.com/Numichi/stackoverflow-angular8/blob/deeplinking-componentless-routes-with-child-routes-in-angular/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

Comment: ok, thanx for your effort anyway!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Stackblitz I made based on your requirements: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m7cc21

The trick is to pass 'x' or 'y' as a parameter of the `'catalog/:id'` route:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "catalog/:id",
    component: CatalogComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        component: ProductComponent,
        outlet: "product",
        children: [{ path: "", component: ItemComponent, outlet: "x" }]
      },
      {
        path: "",
        component: PictureComponent,
        outlet: "picture",
        children: [{ path: "", component: StackComponent, outlet: "y" }]
      }
    ]
  },
];
```

and then display the respective child components inside Product and PictureComponent's `<router-outlet name'x'>`:

```
template: `<h1>ProductComponent</h1>
    <router-outlet *ngIf="id==='x'" name='x'></router-outlet>  
  `
```

In order to detect when the ':id' parameter (x or y) changes you have to subscribe to the route's `paramMap` in `product.component.ts` and `picture.component.ts`:

```
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
      (params: ParamMap) => {
        this.id = params.get('id');
        console.log(this.id);
    });
```

Comment: HAHA! Thank you very much for your effort and example! This is very helpfult. So the solution would be a nice tweak/workaround. But when I am right, the ng Router is not capable of doing it by itselfs, which is strange to me, because the router config does NOT break any algorithm of the router engine.